# React Native AsyncStorage calls have no effect, doesn't enter callback or .then

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, asynccallback, asyncstorage

A question about AsyncStorage. I'm working on a RN app and I need Async storage to keep track of the login state and token for the user.

The behavior I see with AsyncStorage is really inconsistent. With the below code, I should see a console log of the state of the 'loggedIn' variable. Some runs I do see this, some runs I don't. I'm not sure why? I call this in componentwillmount() for my root component. So I don't think there's any behavior interfering beforehand.

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('loggedIn').then((loggedIn) => {
      console.log('loggedIn:');
      console.log(loggedIn);
      if ( loggedIn != null)
      {
        this.state.loggedIn = true;
      }
    });
```

This code at one point used to log like it's expected to, printing 'loggedIn: null', but it stopped printing at one point. Even though I didn't change the code. It seems like it doesn't even enter the .then block.

I've also tried using a callback instead of promises and it still doesn't print the result. 
I don't know what the problem is. Any ideas?

I've downloaded Reactotron  to try and track AsyncStorage's behavior. But it doesn't seem to show any change to AsyncStorage when I try setting a variable in another one of my components, as shown in the code block below.

On successful login I try and save the key, but it also doesn't seem to work. I don't get a console log, and I don't see any changes on Reactotron.

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('key', data.key, () => { AsyncStorage.getItem('key', (err, result) => {
                console.log(result)});});
```

Not sure what other code snippets I need to illustrate the behavior.

Comment: Do you not have a catch on the `AsyncStorage` call? It could be catching an error.

Comment: No I don't, I'll add one and see what the console logs there and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

This should help

```
getData = async () => {
   try{
      await AsyncStorage.getItem('loggedIn', (err, loggedIn) => {
         if(!err && loggedIn!=null){
            this.setState({loggedIn});
         }   
      })
   }catch(e){
      console.log("Error ", e);
   }     
}
```

Don't forget to call `this.getData()` wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Can that help you?

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const setLoggedIn = await AsyncStorage.setItem("loggedIn", true);
  const loggedIn = await AsyncStorage.getItem("loggedIn");
  if (loggedIn) {
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: loggedIn
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Can componentDidMount be async ? I think I read somewhere that it can't be

Comment: You can add async to componentDidMount and it works well. I have done it in quite a few projects.

Comment: `componentDidMount` can be `async`. `componentWillMount` can't. The problem is value in `setItem` is expecting a string, so it's safer to use JSON string

Answer (score 0):

This is the `AsyncStorage` in nutshell.
It only saves string, so you have to do `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` everytime.
Note: `JSON.stringfy(false)` will return `'false'` string. It works, but not recommended.
Also, it's better to keep storage keys as a global constant.

```
import React from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage, Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const storageKeys = {
  loginStatus: 'login-status',
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loggedIn: false,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this._getLoginStatus();
  }

  render() {
    const logInMsg = this.state.loggedIn
      ? 'Welcome back'
      : 'Please log in first!';
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{logInMsg}</Text>
        <Button onPress={this._onLoginPress} title="Toggle login" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _onLoginPress = async () => {
    try {
      console.log('prevState', this.state.loggedIn);
      await this.setState(prevState => ({
        loggedIn: !prevState.loggedIn,
      }));
      const data = JSON.stringify({ loggedIn: this.state.loggedIn });
      console.log('_onLoginPress', data);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(storageKeys.loginStatus, data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  _getLoginStatus = async () => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(storageKeys.loginStatus);
      // JSON.parse(null) will return null
      console.log('_getLoginStatus', jsonValue);
      const value = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
      if (value && value.loggedIn !== null) {
        this.setState({
          loggedIn: value.loggedIn,
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

All the functions should be `async` in this case.

**Update:**
`setState` function also need to have `await`, another way to do this it's to set `AsyncStorage` in the callback function.